# Upgrading Redmine from 3.0.7 to 3.2.0

Tags: redmine

I am trying to upgrade my Redmine 3.0.7 that was installed from the oneclick install to the newest stable version, 3.2.0. However, when I try to run svn update, it says it is updated, but doesn't show as updated in the info on the site. I tried to follow the information here:

```
You can checkout the latest stable source with one of the following commands:

Subversion

svn co https://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/3.2-stable redmine-3.2
It will create a directory named redmine-3.2 and you'll be able to update your Redmine copy using svn update in this directory.
```

The information from the info page on the admin section of my redmine:

```
    Environment:
  Redmine version                3.0.7.stable.15164
  Ruby version                   2.0.0-p643 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  4.2.3
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.8
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upgrade to a newer version of Redmine, specifically 3.2, you will need to switch to the 3.2-stable SVN branch and then perform the upgrade.

First off, I would recommend taking a snapshot of your Droplet so that you have a working state that you can restore in case anything goes wrong with the upgrade. If you can't power off your Droplet to take a snapshot, you can back up the files and settings manually. All uploaded files should be stored in /srv/redmine/files. The database can be backed up by running the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root redmine | gzip > ~/redmine_db_backup.sql.gz
```

Then, switch to the newer SVN branch:

```
cd /srv/redmine
svn switch ^/branches/3.2-stable
```

Make sure all the requires gems are installed and up-to-date:

```
bundle update
```

Next, you'll want to upgrade the database as well so that any changes in the database structure are applied to your existing database:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Finally, clear the cache and restart Passenger. This will log out all users.

```
bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear tmp:sessions:clear RAILS_ENV=production
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

You might also want to check out the Admin -> Roles & permissions page for any new permissions.

Let me know if you have any issues. I've just tested it on a Droplet and everything went fine - so I'm hoping that everything will go smoothly for you as well.